# plot triangular mesh surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a solution, calculated using FEM, on a 2D triangular unstructured mesh using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import cm

# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import


# set up a figure twice as wide as it is tall
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

# set up the axes for the first plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')

# plot a 3D surface
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, XX, cmap=cm.viridis,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim(-100.01, 100.01)
ax.view_init(elev=90, azim=-90)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)
```

Where x and y - arrays of x and y coordinates of nodal points respectively, XX - array of nodal values of some function. I got the following output - see the attached pic. The problem is, that on the left side, there supposed to be a cavern - i.e. a void space with no data, but on the plot it can be seen that there are some weirdly shaped colour filled triangles as well. Is there any way to make it look like on the second picture (which was made in Matlab)? Also side question - is there a way to toggle off this perspective 3D view and make it like a projection like on the second screenshot as well?

[image: python plot]
[image: matlab plot]

Comment: Did you look at [tricontourf](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.tricontourf) ?